# Using wild card to match filepath bash

Tags: bash, wildcard, glob

whitelist. Will be given in an array

`whitelist=(assets/**/* config/mapel-syrup/*/bla-web/**/*)`

```
assets/**/*
config/mapel-syrup/*/bla-web/**/*
```

filepath that should match. Will be given in an array.

`paths=(config/mapel-syrup/common/bla-web/list/file1.log.json config/mapel-syrup/alpine/bla-web/file2.log.json assets/dire1/file3.json)`

```
config/mapel-syrup/common/bla-web/list/file1.log.json
config/mapel-syrup/alpine/bla-web/file2.log.json
assets/dire1/file3.json
```

file path that should not match.

```
config/mapel-syrup/common/not-match/file4.json
assets/mapel-syrup/makelists/aus/MakeLists.txt
```

I am trying to implement a whitelist feature using bash script. I am given an array of `whitelist` directories. There is a second array called `paths` which contains all the files to be changed. The task is simple, check if the paths match with the whitelist, then do echo match, else do nothing.

I tried looking for some solutions in SO, but none of them exactly match the patterns I have. Can an expert help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
paths=(config/mapel-syrup/common/bla-web/list/file1.log.json config/mapel-syrup/alpine/bla-web/file2.log.json assets/dire1/file3.json)
whitelist=(assets/**/* config/mapel-syrup/*/bla-web/**/*)
for p in ${paths[@]}; do
  echo $p
  match=0
  for w in ${whitelist[@]}; do
    [[ $p == $w ]] && match=1
  done
  if [[ $match -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo matches
  else
    echo "no match"
  fi
done
```

Sample output:

```
config/mapel-syrup/common/bla-web/list/file1.log.json
matches
config/mapel-syrup/alpine/bla-web/file2.log.json
no match
assets/dire1/file3.json
matches
```

Comment: Are you sure you are getting matches, no match and matches? I am only getting no match

config/mapel-syrup/common/bla-web/list/file1.log.json
no match
config/mapel-syrup/alpine/bla-web/file2.log.json
no match
assets/dire1/file3.json
no match

Comment: I copied the contents of the script and the output as is from a bash 4.2.46(2) on RHEL7.8. It seems that triplee's edit broke the script. My original version without quotes works fine. I'll see if I can restore the original version.

Comment: @triplee: I understand you probably wanted to add quotes out of best practice. But I assume it breaks because the script is relying on path globing. I haven't looked into the detail but the code as posted originally works but fails when the quotes are added.

Comment: Glad to hear it works. Hope you'll accept my answer then.